# How to make changes to the style of the elements that make up a node module component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor

I npm installed '**react-select**' to my meteor-react project and I was trying to make style changes to the internal elements of the "Select" component from the package. I was able to make style changes in the Developer Options of the browser, but not able to find the source stylesheet to make the changes in.

- Where can I find the stylesheets in the node module/package?
- How do I make style changes to a node module/package?

Comment: Do you have some code? Have you check the [docs](https://react-select.com/home#custom-styles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-select` adds style to element using `JavaScript`. That's why we can not see any `css`/`less`/`scss` files in `node_modules`->`react-select` folder.

**It is not the rule but recommendation that, don't ever try to alter the default style provided, instead override them.**

**My suggestion is override the style in your custom `css` files using the `class-name`/`id` of the element.**